# using xargs as an argument for cut

Tags: bash, unix, cut, cat, xargs

Say i have a file a.txt containing a word, followed by a number, followed by a newline on

```
and 3
now 2
for 2
something 7
completely 8
different 6
```

I need to select the nth char from every word (specified by the number next to the word)

```
cat a.txt | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -i -n1 cut a.txt -c {}
```

I tried this command, which selects the numbers and uses xargs to put them into the -c option from cut, but the cut command gets executed on every line, instead of a.txt being looped (which I had expected to happen) How can I resolve this problem?

EDIT: Since it seems to be unclear, i want to select a character from a word. The character which I need to select can be found next to the word, for example:
and 3, will give me d. I want to do this for the entire file, which will then form a word :)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the result you want to obtain? Please add it to your question.

Comment: If I understand well, the second line should return  "e"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Is my question clear now? Sorry, this is the first time I actually had to ask a question on here, so I don't really know how the formatting works. The word that should be outputted here is 'dooier'

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks for the edit. Next time, please include an example of your desired output. Show it in your question rather than describing it. For help on formatting, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure shell solution:

```
$ while read word num; do echo ${word:$((num-1)):1}; done < a.txt 
d
o
o
i
e
r
```

This is using a classic `while; do ... ; done` shell loop and the `read` builtin. The general format is

```
while read variable1 variable2 ... variableN; do something; done < input_file
```

This will iterate over each line of your input file splitting it into as many variables as you've given. By default, it will split at whitespace but you can change that by changing the `$IFS` variable. If you give a single variable, the entire line will be saved, if you give more, it will populate as many variables as you give it and save the rest in the last one.

In this particular loop, we're reading the word into `$word` and the number into `$num`. Once we have the word, we can use the shell's string manipulation capabilities to extract a substring. The general format is

```
${string:start:length}
```

So, `${string:0:2}` would extract the first two characters from the variable `$string`. Here, the variable is `$word`, the start is the number minus one (this starts counting at 0) and the length is one. The result is the single letter at the position given by the number.

Comment: Ah, so beautiful. Constructs like these are why I love the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you used awk:

```
awk '{print substr($1,$2,1)}' file
```

`substr` takes a substring of the first field starting from the number contained in the second field and of length 1.

Testing it out (using the original input from your question):

```
$ cat file
and 3
now 2
for 2
something 7
completely 8
different 6
$ awk '{print substr($1,$2,1)}' file
d
o
o
i
e
r
```

Comment: Using awk is an elegant solution to this problem, but I am not supposed to use it (this is a homework)

Comment: @user3470438 what _can_ you use? The approach you are trying won't work. What are the constraints you have?

Comment: @terdon I can use sed and unix commands, but not languages like AWK,perl and the like.

Comment: @user3470438 I would say that awk is just as legitimate a core UNIX tool to use as sed.

Comment: @TomFenech I'm not arguing against that, I'm just not allowed to use AWK, only sed and/or commands like cut,xargs,... (i.e the basic commands)